# What language does this mean?

Tags: grammar, context-free-grammar, context-sensitive-grammar

this is the language:

`L = { w belong {a,b,c}* | |w|= 3 * number(a) (w) }`

Then, what does that mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means that L is the language of strings `w` consisting of symbols `'a'`, `'b'`' and `'c'`, where the length of the string `w`  equals to 3 times the number of symbol `'a'` present in the string `w`.

The productions for this grammars should be such that if it add one `'a'` then it also adds two `'b'`, or two `'c'`, or one `'b'`; one  `'c'`.   Check below grammar:

```
S → ^ | SaSMSM |  SMSaSM | SMSMSa   
M → b | c
```

here `^` means epsilon.

To generate `aabbcc` use Right most derivation

1. S → SaSMSM
2. replace first S in rhs by ^ using S → ^
   S → SaSMSM → aSMSM
3. replace S → SaSMSM
   S → SaSMSM → aSaSMSMMSM
4. use S → ^
   S → SaSMSM → aSaSMSMMSM → aaSMSMMSM
5. use S → ^
   S → SaSMSM → aSaSMSMMSM → aaSMSMMSM → aaMSMMSM
6. M → b
   S → SaSMSM → aSaSMSMMSM → aaSMSMMSM → aaMSMMSM → aabSMMSM
7. use S → ^
   S → SaSMSM → aSaSMSMMSM → aaSMSMMSM → aaMSMMSM → aabSMMSM → aabMMSM
8. M → b
   S → SaSMSM → aSaSMSMMSM → aaSMSMMSM → aaMSMMSM → aabSMMSM → aabMMSM → aabbMSM
9. M → c
   S → SaSMSM → aSaSMSMMSM → aaSMSMMSM → aaMSMMSM → aabSMMSM → aabMMSM → aabbMSM → aabbcSM
10. use S → ^
    S → SaSMSM → aSaSMSMMSM → aaSMSMMSM → aaMSMMSM → aabSMMSM → aabMMSM → aabbMSM → aabbcSM → aabbcM
11. M → c
    S → SaSMSM → aSaSMSMMSM → aaSMSMMSM → aaMSMMSM → aabSMMSM → aabMMSM → aabbMSM → aabbcSM → aabbcM → aabbcc

Comment: abc | acb | bac | cab | bca | cba | aabbcc | aabcbc | aabccb | aacbbc | aacbcb | aaccbb are all examples of strings, the first ones have 1 a in them so their length must be 3, the last ones have 2 a's in them so their length must be 6

Comment: ah ok, thank you :) but if I want to generate a grammar, as it would be?

Comment: euhm, a grammar would be:
G -> empty | LG
L -> aMM | MaM | MMa
M -> b|c

I think, you should verify though :)

Comment: @egos then for every one `a` add two other symbols {`b`, `c`}.

Comment: {a,b,c}* means that it is not 0?

Comment: @egos yes, it means language accepts epsilon (null) string.

Comment: @egos Yes context free. You can check in every production LHS has only single production.

Answer (score 0):

S -> aBCS | aBC
S -> BCaS | BCa
S -> BaCS | BaC
S -> aCBS | aCB
S -> CaBS | CaB
S -> CBaS | CBa
B -> b
C -> c

may be right ?

Comment: Although you shouldn't ask question in answer section (instead ask in comment) But your grammar is almost correct except it doesn't accepts nul string ^. See that grammar in above answer and delete this one